# Vectorizing cell find and summing in Matlab

Tags: matlab, performance, vectorization

Would someone please show me how I can go about changing this code from an iterated to a vectorized implementation to speed up performance in Matlab? It takes approximately 8 seconds per `i` for `i=1:20` on my machine currently.

```
classEachWordCount = zeros(nwords_train, nClasses);
for i=1:nClasses % (20 classes)
    for j=1:nwords_train % (53975 words)
        classEachWordCount(j,i) = sum(groupedXtrain{i}(groupedXtrain{i}(:,2)==j,3));
    end
end
```

If context is helpful basically `groupedXtrain` is a cell of 20 matrices which represent different classes, where each class matrix has 3 columns: `document#,word#,wordcount`, and unequal numbers of rows (tens of thousands). I'm trying to figure out the count total of each word, for each class. So `classEachWordCount` should be a matrix of size `53975x20` where each row represents a different word and each column a different label. There's got to be a built-in function to assist in something like this, right?

for example `groupedXtrain{1}` might start off like:

```
doc#,word#,wordcount
    1 1 3
    1 2 1
    1 4 3
    1 5 1 
    1 8 2
    2 2 1
    2 5 4
    2 6 2
```

Comment: Looks like a job for [`accumarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html)

Comment: Thanks that looks promising I'll look into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is mentioned in the comments, you can use `accumarray` to sum up the values in the third column for each unique value in the second column for each class

```
results = zeros(nwords_train, numel(groupedXtrain));

for k = 1:numel(groupedXtrain)
    results(:,k) = accumarray(groupedXtrain{k}(:,2), groupedXtrain{k}(:,3), ...
                              [nwords_train 1], @sum);
end
```

Comment: The problem I'm having with this is I think now each `results{i}` is of different lengths rather than all being of length `nwords_train ` and having zeros for words that aren't found, so I don't know which row total corresponds to which word anymore. Is there a quick fix for that?

Comment: @Jake If you want them all to be the same size, you can specify the size as the third input to `accumarray`. updated

Comment: I'm getting the error:
Error using accumarray
When SUBS is a column vector, the third input SZ must be of the form [N 1].

Comment: Wait actually I think the order of the words is changed in this way. Instead of the zeros being at the locations for each word they're all placed at the end so I still don't know which row corresponds to each word total.

Comment: @Jake Do you not use the same value in column 2 to correspond to the same word for each class? If you do, there should be no issues.

Comment: If I understand what you're asking I think yes, but for instance if results(1:10,1) ends up being [13, 63, 275, 9, 82, 41, 6, 1, 34, 140] This wouldn't necessarily correspond to totals for words 1:10 would it? If for instance the total for word #2 was zero this would correspond to possibly words [1,3:11]?

Comment: @Jake Yes it does correspond to the first 10 words. `accumarray` will automatically fill in a `0` value if there are no mentions of a particular word. For example: `accumarray([1 1 2 3 5].', [1 1 1 0 1], [5 1], @sum)`. Your data must not be as you expect (i.e. the numbers in column 2 for each class correspond to different words.

Comment: Ahh thanks it so happened that coincidentally the first class I checked had no zeros followed by all zeros for totals, but that isn't the case everywhere. Much appreciated.